# Finding a better algorithm for a pilot problem

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I was given this problem:
We have n airplane and we need n pilot to control n airplane. A pilot need to be control pilot or support pilot

Given an array contains the amount of money we need to pay them to be control or support pilot, We need to find the smallest amount of money to pay for n airplane that met the condition below

For example: 5 3 ( 5 is the money we need to pay for the pilot to become control pilot , 3 is the money we need to pay the pilot to become support)

Their experience is already sorted from low to high, a support pilot have to be less experience than the control pilot.

Supposed we have two pilot:

7 1

6 5

The first pilot( 7 1 ) can't be the control pilot since he has less experience than the second pilot ( 6 5 )

Since we have all the information about the problem lets get to input and output:

INPUT:

5 **1**

**9** 8

6 **2**

**10** 9

5 **3**

**6** 1

OUTPUT:

31

Explaination:

```
We choose 9 8, 10 9, 6 1, to become control pilot for each airplane and 5 1, 6 2, 5 3 to become support pilot.
```

So the minimum money we have to pay is : 9 + 10 + 6 + 1 + 2 + 3 = 31

We can't choose 9 8, 10 9, 5 3 to become control pilot and 5 1, 6 2, 6 1 to become support pilot. Obviously the sum of money we need to pay is smaller (which is 9 + 10 + 5 + 1 + 2 + 1) but 6 1 pilot have more experience than 5 3 so 6 1 can't be chosen as support pilot.

My idea is we always choose the first pilot as support and the last pilot as control, that leave us n-2 pilot to handle. Then we find permutation of the rest to see which is smallest and met the condition. But permutation is very slow.

Do we have any algorithm to approach this problem?

Comment: Have you heard of [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) ? This kind of problem can be solved easily and efficiently using LP-solvers.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to formulate this problem as a non-bipartite min-cost matching problem, which could be solved (slowly, but in polynomial time) as a linear program, but due to the special structure of the problem, there's a quadratic-time dynamic program.

We have to designate half of the pilots as support and half as control. This isn't a sufficient condition because (for example) the least senior pilot must be support, and the most, control. What is a necessary and sufficient condition is that, in each prefix of the input, there must be at least as many support pilots as control pilots, and in the whole input, there must be the same number of support and control pilots.

Let `Cost(k, d)` be the cost of assigning the first `k` pilots such that there are `d` more support pilots than control. We get a recurrence

```
Cost(0, d) =
0 if d = 0,
infinity if d ≠ 0.

for all k > 0, Cost(k, d) =
min(Cost(k−1, d−1) + support cost of pilot k, Cost(k−1, d+1) + control cost of pilot k) if d ≥ 0,
infinity if d < 0.
```

Then we evaluate `Cost(n, 0)` with memoization.

Comment: How does the dynamic program satisfy (what I understand as) the constraint that there be a pairing of control-and-support pilots, where in each such pair, the control pilot has more experience than the support pilot?

Comment: @גלעדברקן that's what the `infinity if d < 0` case is for. As long as every prefix has at least as many support pilots as control, there will be a less experienced support for each control.

Comment: Do we initiate d equal 0?

Comment: Oh, because it's sorted to start?

Comment: @Nobody yes, if you're evaluating top down, then you start with Cost(n, 0), and if you're evaluating bottom up, then you start with Cost(0, 0).